# XDebug doesn`t work in VS Code with Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have one problem with XDebug in VS Code, I've tried a lot of things, watched a lot of videos but I don't know what to do.
So the problem is: XDebug doesn't work. In sidebar I don`t see any information about variables and other stuff.
[When started XDebug and reload index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbkMV.png)
There is Dockerfile:
Docker-compose.yml:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
  php-fpm:
    build:
      ./docker
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

launch.json:

```
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "port": 9003,
},
```

And php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Personally I think that, my docker. 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway' doesn`t work.
Here is:
[XDebug Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV33y.png)

I've tried to set xdebug.client_host to static IPAddress on Docker but it doesn`t work because when I rebuild or restart my docker-compose IPAddress changed.

Comment: Your XDebug is setup to run within the php-fpm docker, correct? How did you setup VSCode to connect to that?

Comment: Try to add this line to the xdebug configuration `xdebug.discover_client_host=true` instead of `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal`  and then reload php-fpm in interactive shell(no need to rebuild the service, just to test if it will work) or rebuild it, but without no cache. It will try to get IP address of the client from the headers. According to your screenshot it seems that `xdebug.client_discovery_header` is configured. For more info read [this](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#discover_client_host)